# C++ smart pointer to statically and dynamically allocated resource

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

my base class need to expose a method that for some derived classes would return a smart pointer to dynamically allocated array, and for some other derived classes would return a pointer/reference to statically allocated one.

example:

```
class Base
{
  public:
  virtual ??? foo()=0;
}

class A : public Base
{ 
  private:
  float arr[10];   
  public:
  ??? foo(){ return ???arr; }
}

class B : public Base
{
  public:
  ??? foo(){ 
      allocate array;
      return ???array; 
  }
}
```

The dynamically allocated array is created inside class method and I would prefer to use a `std::unique_ptr`. But what should I do for the statically allocated array in class `A`?

Should I create own class derived from `std::unique_ptr` that would be aware of pointee allocation and would not try to destroy statically allocated pointee, or maybe there  already exist such smart pointers?

Comment: You don't have any statically allocated array in that code. That might be a problem... Anyway, if you had such an array, then `boost::shared_ptr` w/custom deleter would be one option. However, it has some overhead. If the overhead turns out to be unacceptable you can create your own based on `boost::intrusive_ptr`, which doesn't have that overhead problem (dynamic allocation).

Comment: From memory, std::shared_ptr provides a constructor where it can "own" one object, but actually point to another, for exactly this purpose. I can't actually find any evidence of this on MSDN though, and nor can I actually write any code that uses this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can provide custom deleters for [Boost smart pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm). This can also be an empty function that does not do anything. For the class returning a dynamically allocated array, you can use a standard `shared_array`, and for the class returning a pointer to a statically allocated array you can return a `shared_array` with an empty custom deleter.

Note that your problem lies deeper here. Returning a pointer that will be owned by the caller is quit different from returning a pointer owned by the object. You may want to consider not mixing these two in the same function.